# how to randomize the value of a char?

Tags: java, char

So, my problem is, i have a 2-dimension char array. I want to iterate through each element, and randomly assign a value to them. This is my code so far:

```
private char [][] generateTable(int rows, int columns){
        char [][] table = new char [rows][columns];
        return table;
    }

private void tableFiller(char [][] table){
        for (char[] row : table) {
            for (char character : row) {
                randomize(column);
            }
        }
    }

ublic static void randomize(char character){
        Random random = new Random();

        if (random.nextInt(100) < 50){
            character = '.';
        } else {
            character = '*';
        }
    }
```

Now, the randomizer method is not working, and can't figure out why. The IDEA suggests me that the value assigned to character is never used, but that doesn't help tbh. How could i make this method work?

Comment: You don't return the value in `randomize`. It's currently `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem: `void randomize`

Your randomize method returns void, but it should return a character.

Then, that character should be used in the place where the function was called, by assigning it to the relevant array index. I suggest you loop based on an array index to make the assignment easier.

For example, instead of: `for (char character : row)` you would instead write: `for (int i=0; i<row.length; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Because `char` is not a reference. To make it work you should change your randomize method:

```
public static char randomize(){
    Random random = new Random();
    char character;
    if (random.nextInt(100) < 50){
        character = '.';
    } else {
        character = '*';
    }
    return character;
}
```

And call it as it follows:

```
character = randomize();
```

Comment: Whether it was a reference type or primitive type is irrelevant. The reassignment within `randomize` would have no effect outside of it. Also, assigning to `character` won't modify anything in the `row`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the character object with a value  **character = randomize(column);**

```
private void tableFiller(char [][] table){
    for (char[] row : table) {
        for (char character : row) {
           character = randomize(column);
        }
    }
}
```

Or

**randomize(character );**

```
private void tableFiller(char [][] table){
    for (char[] row : table) {
        for (char character : row) {
           randomize(character);
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can do https://stackoverflow.com/a/52370847/9603408